# How to implement a implicit wait for webdriver.findElements() when finding an element list in selenium in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bdd

I have below java code to find a element list. how to implement a implicit wait for it. (without using Thread.sleep(XXX)) ?

```
List<WebElement> datasetList = webDriver.findElements(elementListLocator);
```

Comment: Did you search? https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched documentation or with Google/Bing/etc, and if so what have you searched? I searched for the phrase `seleium webdriver implicit wait java` and received a lot of useful looking links describing how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

**Implicit wait** work at **WebDriver** level.

**Explicit wait** work at **WebElement** level.

If it is just for visibility of list of web elements, you could try something like this :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(List<WebElement> elements));
```

You can just pass the `datasetList` reference in place of elements, that'd do the job.